# xmlns=""(empty) namespace in the child node of SoapFault

Tags: java, soap, glassfish

Our java app using glassfish 2.1 as the server and I deploy the ear file onto glassfish and using soapUI to send a request and expected a soapFault to be returned in the response.
But I got "HTTP Status 500" instead, having look at the server log I found the following:

Caused by: com.sun.xml.stream.XMLStreamException2: xmlns has been already bound to . Rebinding it to mysite.com is an error

Check the debugging log, I found there is a weird empty namespace in the message tag which is the child node of myException. Any idea for how this happened.

```
<ns2:Fault xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <faultcode>ERROR</faultcode>
  <faultstring>Validation Errors</faultstring>
  <detail>
    <myException:myException xmlns:myException="mySite.com" xmlns="mySite.com" xmlns:ns2="wsdl.com">
      <message xmlns="" xmlns:ns7="mySite.com" type="ERROR">
        <ns7:code>code_123</ns7:code>
        <ns7:description>Fault Description</ns7:description>
      </message>
.............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by modify the attributeFormDefault = "qualified" of the xsd file. This will assign each attribute with the targetNamespace. In this case, glassfish will not feel confused then to put a empty namespace.

Not sure this solution can help others but this fix my problem.